# Django - OperationalError: could not connect to server

Tags: python, django

Django Version : 1.5

Python Version : 2.7

`python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000` command used to run the application and the following exception has been generated :

```
OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 8000?
```

The `SETTINGS.py` file for the Django project contains following database settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis', 
        'NAME': 'geodjango',                      
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',              
        'PORT': '8000',
```

}
}

Answer (score 2):

You have invalid settings for `DATABASES`.  Default port for postgres is 5432 (on some installations it is 5433):

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis', 
        'NAME': 'geodjango',                      
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Comment: okay but still its passing exception : `psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

Comment: Did you tried 5433? Which port is set in your postgres configuration?

Comment: yes i tried . i used `pip install` command to install postgresql but its not present in /var/run/ - whats wrong

Comment: `pip` installs the Postgres package for Python, not Postgres itself. Did you install Postgres? Is it up and running?

Comment: A trick you can use to double check the port number that Postures is actually using is `sudo service postgresql status`. It'll say in the status, assuming the server is running.